# Unknown options when running makefiles for linux kernel building

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, ld

I'm building a linux kernel on macbook OS X, and the same error happens whenever I run a make command. I've already tried everything I know, including:

1. Check if any packages need to be installed.
2. Create a case-sensitive disk image.

The linux version I use is stable v5.8.9. Error prompts here:

```
% make defconfig                     
*** Default configuration is based on 'x86_64_defconfig'
ld: unknown option: --version
init/Kconfig:39: syntax error
init/Kconfig:38: invalid statement
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
make[2]: *** [defconfig] Error 1
make[1]: *** [defconfig] Error 2
make: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
```

My software environments using homebrew here:

```
bdw-gc      gmp         libidn2     make        python@3.8
coreutils   gnu-sed     libpng      ncurses     qemu
ctags       gnu-tar     libssh      nettle      readline
elf-header  gnutls      libtasn1    openssl@1.1 snappy
findutils   guile       libtool     p11-kit     sqlite
gdbm        jpeg        libunistring pcre       unbound
gettext     libelf      libusb      pcre2       vde
git         libevent    llvm        pixman      xz
glib        libffi      lzo         pkg-config
```

I think I'm in a very early stage of kernel building, and there must be some simple mistake, does anyone has any ideas?

Comment: You cannot build a Linux kernel on MacOS, unless you install GNU tools.  As far as I'm aware, the Linux kernel still requires GCC and GNU binutils to compile and can't be built with Clang/LLVM.  You may also need to install a newer version of GNU make and other tools as the ones that come with MacOS are ancient versions.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I was trying to do my OS homework on my own PC. So you mean the tools on macbook are either not mainstream or too old to use, and macbook is not supposed to be used for such large scale compiling? Thanks and maybe building it on another linux server is a better choice.

Comment: Macbooks can build large software.  But I'm saying that a Linux kernel build environment is targeted at the tools that are provided on Linux, and MacOS is not the same as Linux.  It uses a completely different compiler and linker (clang vs. GCC), it uses much older versions of many build tools like make, the shell (bash), etc.  It's not clear what you'd do with this kernel once you built it.  You could run it in a virtual machine... you can also compile it in a virtual machine (running Linux) as well.